# Xcode 6 Developer Account Issue

Tags: xcode6, provisioning-profile

I am trying to upload a build on TestFlight and trying to  pass by the step where I have to add developer account to the Xcode preferences. It's partly a good step but I don't like the mess, it creates with certificates and provisioning profiles. Any chance I can either bypass the developer account setup or the provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to deploy your app to actual devices without creating certificates and provisioning profiles. This applies to both Development and Ad Hoc/Testflight distribution.

It's one of the necessary evils of iOS development.

Comment: But it does not make sense. I like to keep my control over my provisioning profiles. How are you managing it?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your issue exactly. Is it that you don't like how Xcode 6 manages the provisioning profiles for you based on your developer account and you would rather download and install only the profiles you think you need on your computer?

Comment: Actually, I have a repo using which I have defined a lot of targets. Each Target uses it's separate provisioning profile and this is here where the issue arises. I have already defined profiles for them. I don't want it to create new profiles for my targets.